# Why return object instead of array?

Tags: php

I do a lot of work in WordPress, and I've noticed that far more functions return objects than arrays. Database results are returned as objects unless you specifically ask for an array. Errors are returned as objects. Outside of WordPress, most APIs give you an object instead of an array.

My question is, why do they use objects instead of arrays? For the most part it doesn't matter too much, but in some cases I find objects harder to not only process but to wrap my head around. Is there a performance reason for using an object?

I'm a self-taught PHP programmer. I've got a liberal arts degree. So forgive me if I'm missing a fundamental aspect of computer science. ;)

Comment: I'm curious about this in regards to the *disadvantages* of objects, like not being able to use `count()` or `array_*()` functions on them (at least in regards to storing/returning key => value data). No one seems to mention it, or am I missing something?

Comment: Objects can be made countable and iterable by implementing Countable or Iterator interfaces.  Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php as well.

Comment: If have SPL installed and you implement the interface countable for your object-class then you can call `count()` on an object.

Comment: In many many cases, an array doesn't even make sense because you don't return a collection of objects, or a kind of collection that isn't easily emulated with arrays. When you just have a sequence of other values and no extra semantics associated, then for god's sake return an array - but you'll find that that's rarely the case.

Comment: @delnan and others:  Please note that @Dennis is talking about [associative arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884068/what-is-the-difference-between-a-map-and-a-dictionary/2884200#2884200), (aka. Dictionaries, aka. Maps), not normal (integer-index) arrays.  These are a core feature of PHP, and serve more or less the same purpose as dynamic classes (`stdClass`).  I'm not sure that this question has an answer other than "Because programmers who work primarily in OOP prefer the semantics of using objects"

Answer (score 64):

These are the reasons why I prefer objects in general:

- Objects not only contain data but also functionality.
- Objects have (in most cases) a predefined structure. This is very useful for API design. Furthermore, you can set properties as public, protected, or private.
- objects better fit object oriented development.
- In most IDE's auto-completion only works for objects.

Here is something to read:

- [Object Vs. Array in PHP](http://www.ehow.com/info_8649735_object-vs-array-php.html)
- [PHP stdClass: Storing Data in an Object Instead of an Array](http://www.webmaster-source.com/2009/08/20/php-stdclass-storing-data-object-instead-array/)
- [When should I use stdClass and when should I use an array in php5 oo code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193765/when-should-i-use-stdclass-and-when-should-i-use-an-array-in-php5-oo-code)
- [PHP Objects vs Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193049/php-objects-vs-arrays)
- [Mysql results in PHP - arrays or objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124240/mysql-results-in-php-arrays-or-objects)
- [PHP objects vs arrays performance myth](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/11568-php-objects-vs-arrays-performance-myth/)
- [A Set of Objects in PHP: Arrays vs. SplObjectStorage](https://web.archive.org/web/20190520205747/http://technosophos.com/2009/05/29/set-objects-php-arrays-vs-splobjectstorage.html)
- [Better Object-Oriented Arrays](http://phpadvent.org/2011/better-object-oriented-arrays-by-ryan-parman)

Comment: the first link seems to be no good? I mean it works, but takes to a different aritcle

Answer (score 24):

This probably isn't something you are going to deeply understand until you have worked on a large software project for several years.  Many fresh computer science majors will give you an answer with all the right words (encapsulation, functionality with data, and maintainability) but few will really understand why all that stuff is good to have.

Let's run through a few examples.

- If arrays were returned, then either all of the values need to be computed up front or lots of little values need to be returned with which you can build the more complex values from.

Think about an API method that returns a list of WordPress posts.  These posts all have authors, authors have names, e-mail address, maybe even profiles with their biographies.

If you are returning all of the posts in an array, you'll either have to limit yourself to returning an array of post IDs:

`[233, 41, 204, 111]`

or returning a massive array that looks something like:

```
[ title: 'somePost', body: 'blah blah', 'author': ['name': 'billy', 'email': 'bill@bill.com', 'profile': ['interests': ['interest1', 'interest2', ...], 'bio': 'info...']] ]
[id: '2', .....]]
```

The first case of returning a list of IDs isn't very helpful to you because then you need to make an API call for each ID in order to get some information about that post.

The second case will pull way more information than you need 90% of the time and be doing way more work (especially if any of those fields is very complicated to build).

An object on the other hand can provide you with access to all the information you need, but not have actually pulled that information yet. Determining the values of fields can be done lazily (that is, when the value is needed and not beforehand) when using an object.

- Arrays expose more data and capabilities than intended

Go back to the example of the massive array being returned. Now someone may likely build an application that iterates over each value inside the post array and prints it. If the API is updated to add just one extra element to that post array then the application code is going to break since it will be printing some new field that it probably shouldn't. If the order of items in the post array returned by the API changes, that will break the application code as well. So returning an array creates all sorts of possible dependencies that an object would not create.

- Functionality

An object can hold information inside of it that will allow it to provide useful functionality to you. A post object, for instance, could be smart enough to return the previous or next posts. An array couldn't ever do that for you.

- Flexibility

All of the benefits of objects mentioned above help to create a more flexible system.

Answer (score 11):

> My question is, why do they use objects instead of arrays?

Probably two reasons:

- WordPress is quite old
- arrays are faster and take less memory in most cases
- easier to serialize

> Is there a performance reason for using an object?

No. But a lot of good other reasons, for example:

- you may store logic in the objects (methods, closures, etc.)
- you may force object structure using an *interface*
- better autocompletion in IDE
- you don't get notices for not undefined array keys
- in the end, you may easily convert any object to array

[OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) != [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) :)

(For example, in Ruby, everything is an object. PHP was procedural/scripting language previously.)

Answer (score 7):

WordPress (and a fair amount of other PHP applications) use objects rather than arrays, for conceptual, rather than technical reasons.

An object (even if just an instance of stdClass) is a representation of one thing. In WordPress that might be a post, a comment, or a user. An array on the other hand is a collection of things. (For example, a list of posts.)

Historically, PHP hasn't had great object support so arrays became quite powerful early on. (For example, the ability to have arbitrary keys rather than just being zero-indexed.) With the object support available in PHP 5, developers now have a choice between using arrays or objects as key-value stores. Personally, I prefer the WordPress approach as I like the syntactic difference between 'entities' and 'collections' that objects and arrays provide.

Answer (score 6):

> My question is, why do they (Wordpress) use objects instead of arrays?

That's really a good question and not easy to answer. I can only assume that it's common in Wordpress to use `stdClass` objects because they're using a database class that by default returns records as a `stdClass` object. They got used to it (8 years and more) and that's it. I don't think there is much more thought behind the simple fact.

> *syntactic sugar for associative arrays*
>   -- **Zeev Suraski** [about the standard object](http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/1717) since PHP 3

- `stdClass` objects are not really better than arrays. They are pretty much the same. That's for some historical reasons of the language as well as `stdClass` objects are really limited and actually are only sort of [value objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ValueObject) in a very basic sense.
- `stdClass` objects store values for their members like an array does per entry. And that's it.
- Only PHP freaks are able to create `stdClass` objects with private members. There is not much benefit - if any - doing so.
- `stdClass` objects do not have any methods/functions. So no use of that in Wordpress.
- Compared with `array`, there are far less helpful functions to deal with a list or semi-structured data.

However, if you're used to arrays, just cast:

```
$array = (array) $object;
```

And you can access the data previously being an object, as an array. Or you like it the other way round:

```
$object = (object) $array;
```

Which will only drop invalid member names, like numbers. So take a little care. But I think you get the big picture: There is not much difference as long as it is about arrays and objects of `stdClass`.

**Related:**

- [Converting to object <sup>**PHP Manual**</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting)
- [Reserved Classes <sup>**PHP Manual**</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php)
- [What is stdClass in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php)

Answer (score 5):

1. The code looks cooler that way
2. Objects pass by reference
3. Objects  are more strong typed then arrays, hence lees pron to errors (or give you a meaningful error message when you try to use un-existing member)
4. All the IDEs today have auto-complete, so when working with defined objects, the IDE does a lot for you and speeds up things
5. Easilly encapsulate logic **and** data in the same box, where with arrays, you store the data in the array, and then use a set of different function to process it.
6. Inheritance, If you would have a similar array with almost but not similar functionality, you would have to duplicate more code then if you are to do it with objects

Probably some more reason I have thought about

Comment: "# Objects pass by reference": That's wrong. Objects do not pass as a PHP variable reference. They never did.

Comment: @hakre - are you on php4? or please elaborate what you mean.

Comment: Well not that wordpress was not PHP 4 until recently but in PHP 4 or PHP 5, objects do not pass as reference: *"One of the key-points of PHP5 OOP that is often mentioned is that "objects are passed by references by default". This is not completely true. This section rectifies that general thought using some examples."* [Objects and references](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php)

Comment: @hakre - I see what you mean, but for all purposes, the language behaves as if you pass references only.

Answer (score 5):

There are several reasons to return objects:

1. Writing `$myObject->property` requires fewer "overhead" characters than `$myArray['element']`
2. Object can return data and functionality; arrays can contain only data.
3. Enable chaining: `$myobject->getData()->parseData()->toXML();`
4. Easier coding: IDE autocompletion can provide method and property hints for object.

In terms of performance, arrays are often faster than objects. In addition to performance, there are several reasons to use arrays:

1. The the functionality provided by the array_*() family of functions can reduce the amount of coding necessary in some cases.
2. Operations such as count() and foreach() can be performed on arrays. Objects do not offer this (unless they implement [Iterator](http://php.net/manual/class.iterator.php) or [Countable](http://php.net/manual/countable.count.php)).

Answer (score 4):

Objects are much more powerful than arrays can be. 
Each object as an instance of a class can have functions attached.
If you have data that need processing then you need a function that does the processing.
With an array you would have to call that function on that array and therefore associate the logic yourself to the data.
With an object this association is already done and you don't have to care about it any more.

Also you should consider the OO principle of information hiding. Not everything that comes back from or goes to the database should be directly accessible.

Comment: Wordpress returns objects of the class `StdClass`. Those objects do not have anything in common of what you highlight. They have no functions for example and they don't have inheritance. And in case of Wordpress, all class variables are public.

Comment: Yes that is true. I think in this case it is, as others stated, just depending on what you prefer. I am not into wordpress but probably they encapsulate all database calls and therefore cannot provide any specialized class for returning. But my answer was in general and I think similar considerations were made by the makers...        Or they just threw a coin.

Comment: They just use a database helper class that returns `stdClass` objects by default since ca. 8 years. If you want to get an array, you need to set an optional parameter to get it.

Answer (score 2):

It's usually not going to be because of performance reasons. Typically, objects cost more than arrays.

For a lot of APIs, it probably has to do with the objects providing other functionality besides being a storage mechanism. Otherwise, it's a matter of preference and there is really no benefit to returning an object vs an array.

Comment: In PHP5, the difference in performance between arrays and objects is marginal.

Answer (score 2):

An array is just an index of values. Whereas an object contains methods which can generate the result for you. Sure, sometimes you can access an objects values directly, but the "right way to do it" is to access an objects methods (a function operating on the values of that object).

```
$obj = new MyObject;
$obj->getName();   // this calls a method (function), so it can decide what to return based on conditions or other criteria

$array['name'];   // this is just the string "name". there is no logic to it.
```

Sometimes you are accessing an objects variables directly, this is usually frowned upon, but it happens quite often still.

```
$obj->name;   // accessing the string "name" ... not really different from an array in this case.
```

However, consider that the MyObject class doesn't have a variable called 'name', but instead has a first_name and last_name variable.

```
$obj->getName();  // this would return first_name and last_name joined.
$obj->name;  // would fail...
$obj->first_name; 
$obj->last_name; // would be accessing the variables of that object directly.
```

This is a very simple example, but you can see where this is going. A class provides a collection of variables and the functions which can operate on those variables all within a self-contained logical entity. An instance of that entity is called an object, and it introduces logic and dynamic results, which an array simply doesn't have.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time objects are just as fast, if not faster than arrays, in PHP there isn't a noticeable difference. the main reason is that objects are more powerful than arrays. Object orientated programming allows you to create objects and store not only data, but functionality in them, for example in PHP the MySQLi Class allows you to have a database object that you can manipulate using a host of inbuilt functions, rather than the procedural approach.

So the main reason is that OOP is an excellent paradigm. I wrote an article about why using OOP is a good idea, and explaining the concept, you can take a look here: http://tomsbigbox.com/an-introduction-to-oop/

As a minor plus you also type less to get data from an object - $test->data is better than $test['data'].

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with word press. A lot of answers here suggest that a strength of objects is there ability to contain functional code. When returning an object from a function/API call it shouldn't contain utility functions. Just properties.

**The strength in returning objects is that whatever lies behind the API can change without breaking your code.**

Example: You get an array of data with key/value pairs, key representing the DB column. If the DB column gets renamed your code will break.

Answer (score 1):

Im running the next test in php 5.3.10 (windows) :

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
    $x = array();
    $x['a'] = 'a';
    $x['b'] = 'b';
}
```

and

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
    $x = new stdClass;
    $x->a = 'a';
    $x->b = 'b';
}
```

Copied from http://atomized.org/2009/02/really-damn-slow-a-look-at-php-objects/comment-page-1/#comment-186961

Calling the function for 10 concurrent users and 10 times (for to obtain an average) then

- Arrays : 100%
- Object : 214% – 216% (2 times slower).

AKA, Object it is still painful slow.   OOP keeps the things tidy however it should be used carefully.

What Wordpress is applying?. Well, both solutions, is using objects, arrays and object & arrays, Class **wpdb** uses the later (and it is the heart of Wordpress).

Comment: You should see the comparison on PHP 5.4. Performance of objects is outstanding and sometimes even faster than Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

It follows the boxing and unboxing principle of OOP. While languages such as Java and C# support this natively, PHP does not. However it can be accomplished, to some degree in PHP, just not eloquently as the language itself does not have constructs to support it.  Having box types in PHP could help with chaining, keeping everything object oriented and allows for type hinting in method signatures.  The downside is overhead and the fact that you now have extra checking to do using the â€œinstanceofâ€ construct.  Having a type system is also a plus when using development tools that have intellisense or code assist like PDT. Rather than having to google/bing/yahoo for the method, it exists on the object, and you can use the tool to provide a drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Although the points made about objects being more than just data are valid since they are usually data and behaviour there is at least one pattern mentioned in [Martin Fowler's "Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture"](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/)  that applies to this type of cenario in which you're transfering data from one system (the application behind the API) and another (your application).

Its the [Data Transfer Object](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) - An object that carries data between processes in order to reduce the number of method calls.

So if the question is whether APIs should return a DTO or an array I would say that if the performance cost is negligible then you should choose the option that is more maintainable which I would argue is the DTO option... but of course you also have to consider the skills and culture of the team that is developing your system and the language or IDE support for each of the options.