# Best practice for returning in PHP function/method

Tags: php, function, methods, return, code-standards

I am refactoring an extensive codebase overtime. In the long run we are going to develop the whole system in classes but in the mean time I am using the opportunity to refine my PHP skills and improve some of the legacy code we use across several hundred websites.

I have read conflicting articles over time about how best to return data from a custom function, generally the debate falls into two categories, those concerned about best technical practice and those concerned about ease of reading and presentation.

I am interesting in opinions (with elaboration) on what you consider best practice when returning from a custom PHP function.

I am undecided as to which of the following as a better standard to follow using this basic theoretical function for example;

**Approach a.**

Populating a return variable and returning it at the end of the function:

```
<?php
function theoreticalFunction( $var )
{
    $return = '';
    if( $something > $somethingelse ){
       $return = true;
    }else{
       $return = false;
    }
    return $return;
}
?>
```

**Approach b.**

Returning at each endpoint:

```
<?php
function theoreticalFunction( $var )
{
    if( $something > $somethingelse ){
       return true;
    }else{
       return false;
    }
}
?>
```

A possible duplicate could have been [What is the PHP best practice for using functions that return true or false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643080/what-is-the-php-best-practice-for-using-functions-that-return-true-or-false) however this is not limited to simply true or false despite my basic example above.

I have looked through the PSR guidelines but didn't see anything (but I may have missed it so please feel free to point me to PSR with reference :) ).

**Extending the original question:**

Is the method used to return different depending on the expected/desired output type?

Does this method change depending on the use of procedural or object oriented programming methods? As this question shows, object orientation brings in its own eccentricities to further extend the possible formatting/presentation options [Best practices for returns methods in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968685/best-practices-for-returns-methods-in-php)

Please try to be clear in your explanations, I am interested in WHY you choose your preferred method and what, if anything, made you choose it over another method.

Comment: I prefer using approach B. for example I have a function where the user needs to be logged in so my first line would check that. i dont want to build a huge if statement to make sure the script does not execute the rest. so thats why I prefer using approach B

Comment: There are people arguing for *single exit points* in functions (only one `return` at the end), and others that argue for *fail/return early*. It's simply a matter of opinion and readability/comprehensibility on a case-by-case basis. There is hardly any objective technical answer.

Comment: I think this will end up in: *primarily opinion based*, since it depends and what you want to do; experience of the coder;

Comment: That makes sense @deceze and I did wonder if I would get mostly "it depends on the function in question, case by case" answers. Maybe there isn't a debate to be had here? This could explain the lack of info on this subject within the PSR guidelines, or at least as far as I have seen.

Comment: It's simply not something that can be prescribed dogmatically, period. Some algorithms are better expressed as A and others work better as B.

Comment: @deceze, would you like to add both your comments as an answer? Thank you for your input, it makes sense and has given me something to further investigate myself :)

Comment: BTW, let's not even start getting into your *horrible* use of whitespace and brackets... ;-P

Comment: I've added a vote to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are people arguing for *single exit points* in functions (only one `return` at the end), and others that argue for *fail/return early*. It's simply a matter of opinion and readability/comprehensibility on a case-by-case basis. There is hardly any objective technical answer.

The reality is that it's simply not something that can be prescribed dogmatically. Some algorithms are better expressed as A and others work better as B.

In your specific case neither is "best"; your code should be written as:

```
return $something > $somethingelse;
```

That would hopefully serve as example that there's simply no such thing as a generally applicable rule.

Comment: That makes allot of sense and is logical to me. Thanks for your answer to what is probably a silly/obvious question to you :) .

Comment: Meh... Programmers like to argue about such things, I can understand the impetus. The thing is that if you're around long enough you'll simply realise that all that arguing just turns into flamewars and is ultimately pointless.

Comment: :) which is why I tend to avoid asking questions here as reasonable and friendly debate is rare. Hense my appreciation of the discussion had here. Sometimes its nice to discuss even relatively simple subjects to challenge your views and understanding. We're all here to learn, right?

Comment: Yes indeed. I applaud you for a well phrased question and am glad myself that it was generally well received today.

Comment: @deceze generally I would say now there is a close vote reason for: *primarily opinion based*. But the answer itself is nicely written and I can kinda see how this could get asked in the future/help other SO visitors. And as you said: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293931/should-one-answer-terribly-poor-questions/293946#comment191662_293946 :)

Comment: @Rizier Right, trying to lead by example here. If the answer is "it's opinion based" and that's the answer, then we may as well answer it that way.

Comment: To be fair I knew this was going to be more opinion from the outset and overlooked that SO isnt generally happy with opinion based questions although it would be nice to generate some debate sometimes. I guess I should be looking towards a forum for that :) Although this demo-straights good access to experienced developers, I really do value the chance to hear your honest and friendly opinion on my question, it provided value to me and no doubt others, its a shame it isnt an accepted format on stackoverflow :)

Comment: @John This is getting a bit meta for comments, but I'm all for getting more questions like this on the site, especially to counter the regular debug-my-codez stuff. It simply needs to be phrased well to invite good answers, which is the  tricky part.

Answer (score 7):

I tend towards early returns - leave the function as soon as you know what is going on. One type of this use if called a '[Guard Clause](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuardClause)'

Other things I will often do include dropping final `else` for a default:

```
if ($something > $somethingelse) {
   return true;
}
return false;
```

and in fact, conditions of the form `if (boolean) return true; else return false`, can be shortened even further (if it is clearer to you) to just `return ($something > $somethingelse);`. Extracting a complex if clause from code like this to a usefully named function can help clear up the meaning of code a lot.

Comment: I think I answered my own question by using such a basic example as yourself and deceze have both said about shortening my specific example using very clean, short PHP. It is obvious now how different each method would be, especially when working towards a more object oriented approach (simple, single purpose functions).

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old but the it is interesting and according to me
there are many things to say about it.
The first thing to say is that there is no real standard about returning in functions or methods.
It's usually ruled by the rules your team has decided to follow, but if you are the only one on this refactoring you can do what you think better.

In the case of returning a value the important thing I guess is
**readability**. Sometimes it's better to loose a little bit
of performance for a code that is more readable and maintainable.
I will try to show some examples with pros and cons.

#### Approach A

```
<?php
function getTariableType($var = null)
{
    if (null === $var) {
        return 0;
    } elseif (is_string($var)) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

**Pros:**

- Explicitness. Each case explains itself, even without any comments.
- Structure. There is a branch for each case, every case is delimited clearly
  and it's easy to add a statement for a new case.

**Cons:**

- Readability. All these `if..else` with brackets make the code hard to read and
  we really have to pay attention to every part to understand.
- Not required code. The last `else` statement is not required and the code would be
  easier to read if the `return -1` was only the last statement of the function,
  outside of any `else`.

#### Approach B

```
<?php
function isTheVariableNull($var)
{
    return (null === $var);
}
```

**Pros:**

- Readability. The code is easy to read and understand, at the first look we
  know that the function is checking whether the variable is null.
- Conciseness. There is only one statement and in this case it's fine and clear.

**Cons:**

- Limit. This notation is limited to really little funtions. Using this notation
  or even ternary operator becomes harder to understand in more complicated
  functions.

#### Approach C.1

```
<?php
function doingSomethingIfNotNullAndPositive($var)
{
    if (null !== $var) {
        if (0 < $var) {
            //Doing something
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

**Pros:**

- Explicitness. Each case is explicit we can **reconstruct** the logic of the
  function when reading it.

**Cons:**

- Readability. When adding many `if..else` statements the code is really less
  readable. The code is then indented many times looks dirty. Imagine the code
  with six nested `if`.
- Difficulty to add code. Because the logic seems complex (even if it is not),
  it's difficult to add code or logic into the function.
- Plenty of logic. If you have many `if..else` nested it is perhaps because you
  should create a second function. NetBeans IDE for example suggests you to create
  an other function that handles the logic of all your nested blocks. A function
  should be **atomic**, it should do only one thing. If it does too much work, has
  too much logic, it's hard to maintain and understand. Creating an other function
  may be a good option.

#### Approach C.2

This approch aims to present an alternative to the C.1 notation.

```
<?php
function doingSomethingIfNotNullAndPositive($var)
{
    if (null === $var) {
        return -1;
    } elseif (0 >= $var) {
        return 0;
    }
    //Doing something
}
```

**Pros:**

- Readability. This notation is very readable. It's
  easy to understand what result we will get according to a given value.
- Explicitness. As C.1, this approach is explicit in every branch of the
  condition.

**Cons:**

- Difficulty to add logic. If the function becomes a bit more complicated,
  adding logic would be difficult because we may need to move all the branches of the
  condition.

#### Approach D

```
<?php
function kindOfStrlen($var)
{
    $return = -1;
    if (is_string($var)) {
        $return = strlen($var);
    }
    return $return;
}
```

**Pros:**

- Default value. In this structure we can see that the default value is handled
  from the beginning. We have logic in our function, but if we enter in no
  branch we have a value anyway.
- Ease to add logic. If we need to add a branch `if` it's easy and it does not
  change the structure of the function.

**Const:**

- Not required variable. In this case the `$return` variable is not required, we
  would write the same function without using it. The solution would be to
  `return -1` at the end, and return `strlen($var)` in the if, and it would not
  be less readable.

### Conclusion

I have not listed all the possible notation here, only some of them. What we can
think about them is there is no perfect one, but in some cases an approach seems
better that an other. For example an *is_null* function would be fine with the
approach B.

Using an approach or an other is really up to you, the important thing is to
choose a logic and to keep it during all your project.

Answer (score 0):

Using the approach b is more fine with me because in approach a you have written very few lines of code, but if there are many lines of code and many return statements, then are chances that i will somewhere use the wrong return type, where $return was assigned a some other place and i did not notice that.

Answer (score 0):

I prever variant b. Not only is it more readable ( you know exactly that you do not need to consider any of the remaining code after a `return` statement), but it is also more failsafe.

If you either have a bug in the remaining code, or you encounter a set of conditions you did not take into account when designing the system, it would be possible that your result is changed. This cannot happen when you exit the function with `return [$someVariable]`;

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function theoreticalFunction( $var )
{
    if( $something > $somethingelse ){
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
?>
```

This approach can also be used as on RETURN Statement, the program cursor is returned back and the next statement will not be executed.