# Echo is not printing the object value

Tags: php, mysql

If I un comment `print_r($dateTime)` then this statement working fine `echo $dateTime->date;`

Why this is happening . Give me suggestions please.

```
 $current_date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 $dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $current_date, (new DateTimeZone('UTC')));

 $dateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('PST'));
 //print_r($dateTime); //If I print object then below echo stmt is working 

  echo $dateTime->date;
```

Getting Following Error

```
Notice: Undefined property: DateTime::$date in C:\xampp\htdocs\datetime.php
```

Comment: what is your php version ?

Comment: My PHP version is  5.5.9

Comment: Side note: you don't need `date()` at all. If you use `DateTime`, stick to it. Mixing different date formats can only add confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `DateTime` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) does not have a property called `date`.

You are probably looking for [`DateTime::format(string)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to output a date with a specific format.
For example:

```
echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i')
// prints: 2014-05-13 12:29
```

Comment: Yes !! It's working. But it's giving the object like this DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2014-05-13 05:40:09
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/Los_Angeles
)

Comment: @user3580413 - That's impossible. You aren't running Cobra's code at all.

Comment: how to call the  DateTime object value date

Comment: It displaying the date with this statement  echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i') @ÁlvaroG.Vicario

Comment: @user3580413 - You don't call any `date` property. I've just composed an answer about that. Cobra's answer is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Add `print_r($dateTime,1);` prior to your `echo $dateTime->date;` and your code will work as expected.

The code..

```
<?php
$current_date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $current_date, (new DateTimeZone('UTC')));
$dateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('PST'));
print_r($dateTime,1);  //<-- Add this
echo($dateTime->date); // 2014-05-13 03:35:44
```

#### [Demo](https://eval.in/150498)

Comment: This is really funny. `print_r()` has the side effect of actually creating a `date` public property. Yet it's a static property, it won't reflect any change to the object (until you call `print_r()` again).

Comment: But `$dateTime` is not _static_ in this case right.?

Comment: I mean `$dateTime->date`. If you do `$dateTime->modify('-1234 days')` then `$dateTime->date` keeps its old value (until you call `print_r()` again). It's all clearly a hack of whoever added `print_r()` support to `DateTime` objects and I'm sure not many PHP developers know it. It isn't especially useful but it's a cool finding.

Comment: Related: [print_r() adds properties to DateTime objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066034/print-r-adds-properties-to-datetime-objects)

Answer (score 1):

The public methods and properties of the `DateTime` class are [documented in the PHP manual](http://php.net/datetime). As the error message suggests, there's no `date` property among them. In fact, the class does not have any public property at all, only constants and methods.

As with almost any other object, the only reliable way to cast to string is to use a dedicated method. In `DateTime`, the method is `format()`.

`DateTime` is a native object written in C, not a pure PHP class. Thus, `print_r()` and equivalent functions don't necessarily show the same information as with regular objects.