# How to get key's value from object?

Tags: php, datetime, object

I need to pull the date from the object below and nothing (`$obj->date`, `$obj['date']`, etc.) I've tried has worked. I'm not sure if what I'm searching for isn't correct, but I can't find anything in searches as to how to grab "2015-08-12 15:47:04".

Can someone tell me how to get it and describe what everything is called? Is it correct to say that I need to get the value of the first key from an object?

```
object(DateTime)#630 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2015-08-12 15:47:04"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$now = new DateTime(NULL);

echo $now->format("Y-m-d h:i:s");
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

also see related: [Why can't I access DateTime->date in PHP's DateTime class? Is it a bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084222/why-cant-i-access-datetime-date-in-phps-datetime-class-is-it-a-bug) and [print_r() adds properties to DateTime objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066034/print-r-adds-properties-to-datetime-objects)