# DateTime instance property changes due to a var_dump() or print_r()

Tags: php, datetime, var-dump

I have the following code:

```php
<?php

$date = new DateTime;
var_dump($date);
$date->timezone = 'Europe/Madrid';
var_dump($date->timezone);  // Shows 'Europe/Madrid'
var_dump($date);            // Shows 'UTC' (!)
var_dump($date->timezone);  // Shows 'UTC' (!!)
```

which shows the following output:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2017-11-08 21:21:15.596968"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
string(13) "Europe/Madrid"
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2017-11-08 21:21:15.596968"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
string(3) "UTC"
```

Why `$date->timezone` changes back from 'Europe/Madrid' to 'UTC' when I do a simple `var_dump($date)`???

Using `print_r()` instead of `var_dump()` has the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timezone` is not a property of a new `DateTime` class. You can verify that by trying to access it immediately after creating the DateTime object.

```
$date = new DateTime;
echo $date->timezone;
```

This will get you an undefined property notice.

PHP creates the `timezone` property to display when you do `print_r` or `var_dump` on the object, but modifying that property does not modify the underlying data.

The next time you `var_dump` or `print_r` the object, the display properties will be regenerated, overwriting your changes.

You can use the [`setTimezone`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) method instead if you really do need to change the timezone.

```
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Madrid'));
```

(Or set the timezone in your PHP configuration.)

---

Interestingly enough, referring directly to the `timezone` property still shows the old value even after you update it with `setTimezone`. Apparently you need to `var_dump` the  whole object for it to recreate those properties.

```
$date = new DateTime;
var_dump($date);     // Shows 'UTC'
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Madrid'));
var_dump($date->timezone);  // Still shows 'UTC' (!)
var_dump($date);            // Shows 'Europe/Madrid'
var_dump($date->timezone);  // Shows 'Europe/Madrid'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please elaborate the underlying mechanism used by PHP to display non-existing properties when using `print_r()` or `var_dump()`? How can PHP do that?

Comment: If you want more information on this known "bug" - https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75232

Comment: @RicardoPérezLópez There are also some other questions on SO about this this that go into some more detail. [Here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066034/print-r-adds-properties-to-datetime-objects)

Comment: I considered closing this Q as a duplicate of that, but I wanted to specifically show you how you could set the timezone.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Don'tPanic. Interestingly, PysSH has a bizarre behaviour. `$date = new DateTime; echo $date->timezone;` shows the time zone.