# Why I can only reach my date object when I dump() it before using it?

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, var-dump

Why I can only reach my date object when I `dump()` it before using it?

Here is my function:

```
public function checkSubscriptionEndDate($user){

    $subscriptionEndDate = $user->getSubscriptionEndDate();

    dump($subscriptionEndDate);

    if($subscriptionEndDate==null){
        $subscriptionEndDateMessage = $this->get('translator')->trans('subscriptionEndDateMessage');
        $subscriptionStatus = "error";
    }else{

        $subscriptionEndDateDate = $subscriptionEndDate->date;
        // CHECK IF SUBSCRIPTION END DATE IS BEFORE NOW
        if (date('now') < $subscriptionEndDateDate) {
            dump('before');
            $subscriptionStatus = "success";
            $subscriptionEndDateMessage = $this->get('translator')->trans('subscriptionStatusSuccess').' '.date('d/m/Y',strtotime($subscriptionEndDateDate));
        }else{
            dump('after');
            $subscriptionStatus = "error";
            $subscriptionEndDateMessage = $this->get('translator')->trans('subscriptionStatusError').' '.date('d/m/Y',strtotime($subscriptionEndDateDate));
        }   
    }

    return array(
        'subscriptionEndDateMessage' => $subscriptionEndDateMessage,
        'subscriptionStatus' => $subscriptionStatus
    );

    return $subscriptionEndDateMessage;

}
```

When I do this, the page loads as expected, there is no problem. But if I remove this line:

`dump($subscriptionEndDate);`

I can no more load the `$subscriptionEndDate->date` as illustrated in this error page:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the code of your  `DateTime` class?

Answer (score 7):

This looks like another example of [this strange-looking thing with `var_dump`/`print_r` and `DateTime` objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066034/print-r-adds-properties-to-datetime-objects) that people often ask about.

The `date` property is added to the DateTime object in `$subscriptionEndDate` by the dump function, to provide a human readable representation of the internal data, but it isn't a property of the object by default.

Instead of getting the string, you can just create a new DateTime object to represent the current date and time. [Those objects are directly comparable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961074/how-do-i-compare-two-datetime-objects-in-php-5-2-8) ([since PHP 5.2.2](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.changelog)).

So instead of this:

```
$subscriptionEndDateDate = $subscriptionEndDate->date;
// CHECK IF SUBSCRIPTION END DATE IS BEFORE NOW
if (date('now') < $subscriptionEndDateDate) {
```

use this:

```
$now = new DateTime;
// CHECK IF SUBSCRIPTION END DATE IS BEFORE NOW
if ($now < $subscriptionEndDate) {
```

If you haven't converted `$subscriptionEndDate` to the string `$subscriptionEndDateDate`, this later part won't work:

```
date('d/m/Y',strtotime($subscriptionEndDateDate)
```

So you can use the [`format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method instead.

```
$subscriptionEndDate->format('d/m/Y')
```

<sub>This seems better anyway, in my opinion, because you won't be converting from DateTime to string to timestamp back to string, you'll just go directly to string once.</sub>

Comment: You sir, are a life saver! I had that like 2 years ago too and I couldnt manage it to work lol. The project is dead by now, but please sir, take my upvote.

Comment: @Manuel glad I could help? :) If help is even the right word for it at this point...

Comment: Ill bookmark your answer for sure, maybe you can help my future me :)
Its the same thing as die/exit with numbers between 1-255 when debugging, it drove me really mad haha